# How can I insert JSON data directly elastic search using curl command?

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm trying to insert data directly to elastic search into a specific index called "cars" via the curl command but it is constantly encountering errors.

```
curl -XPOST http://elk.local:9200/cars/my_doc -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @test.json
```

JSON example:

```
{
"name":"John",
"age":30,
"cars":[ "Ford", "BMW", "Fiat" ]
}
```

Error:

```
{"error":{"root_cause":[{"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [cars] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [my_doc, log]"}],"type":"illegal_argument_exception","reason":"Rejecting mapping update to [cars] as the final mapping would have more than 1 type: [my_doc, log]"},"status":400}
```

any ideas how to do it correctly?

Comment: `Important`
Multiple mapping types are not supported in indices created in 6.0

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest looking at your mapping and adjusting so there is only **one type in a single index**

**From the ES documentation:**

> Indices created in Elasticsearch 6.0.0 or later may only contain a
>   single mapping type. Indices created in 5.x with multiple mapping
>   types will continue to function as before in Elasticsearch 6.x.
>   Mapping types will be completely removed in Elasticsearch 7.0.0.

In your case it seems your cars index have **2 types** one is `my_doc` and another is `log` that's why you're getting this error

> Rejecting mapping update to [cars] as the final mapping would have
>   more than 1 type: [my_doc, log]

See: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.0/removal-of-types.html

Comment: So, what I need to do?

Comment: I would suggest looking at your mapping and adjusting so there is only **one type in a single index**

Answer (score 0):

From the request I see that you are using ‘GET’ to insert data which is not correct. Use POST instead.

Comment: Got this error:  {"error":"Incorrect HTTP method for uri [/cars/] and method [POST], allowed: [PUT, HEAD, GET, DELETE]","status":405}

Comment: @bugnet17 try PUT and note that only one mapping type is supported in ES 6.x